# How to represent Abstract Time in Julia

Tags: julia

I am trying to represent Abstract Time in Julia but was unable to find it referenced in the Standard Library's Dates section. Is there a way to represent Abstract Time in Julia by doing something like `Year(1) + Day(1)`?

The reason I ask is that some code I want to test dispatches on `Dates.AbstractTime` so I need to pass the appropriate type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this functionality is already present in the language:

```
julia> using Dates

julia> Year(2)+Month(3)+Day(100)
2 years, 3 months, 100 days
```

However, if you want your very special `AbstractTime` operator here is a toy example that should be useful:

```
struct MyTime <: Dates.AbstractTime
    value::Float64
end
days(d::Day) = d.value
days(h::Hour) = h.value/24
days(m::Minute) = m.value/24/60
days(m::MyTime) = m.value
⊕(a::Dates.AbstractTime, b::Dates.AbstractTime) = MyTime(days(a)+days(b))
```

Example usage:

```
julia> Day(1) ⊕ Hour(12) ⊕ Minute(6)
MyTime(1.5041666666666667)
```

Comment: The function signature is as follows: `function pretty_time(T::Dates.AbstractTime)` so doing `pretty_time(Year(2)+Month(3)+Day(100))` does not work unfortunatly.

Comment: Try `typeof(Year(2)+Month(3)+Day(100)) <: Dates.AbstractTime` to see that it is actually a subtype of  `Dates.AbstractTime`. Hence if it does not work you have some problem in other part of your code,